# On hover select all the tiles instead of one

Tags: flutter, dart

Going with the mouse hover one tile of my ReordableListView.
I should see the edit and delete icons, together with a change of color. What I have is that selecting one tile, I see the behavior on all the tiles instead of just the one selected.

[image]
Here is a snippet of my code.

```
ReorderableListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
      buildDefaultDragHandles: false,
      children: <Widget>[
        for (int index = 0; index < widget.fieldsList.length; index += 1)
          ListTile(
            key: Key('$index'),
            leading: SizedBox(
              width: 50,
              child: ReorderableDragStartListener(
                index: index,
                child: const Icon(Icons.drag_handle)
              ),
            ),
            title: MouseRegion(
              onEnter: (details) => setState(() => isHover = true),
              onExit: (details) => setState(() => isHover = false),
              onHover: (details) => setState(() => isHover = true),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                      color: isHover
                          ? Colors.grey.shade100
                          : Colors.transparent,
                      child:
                          showComponent(componentList[index].type)),
                  Positioned(
                      top: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      child: isHover
                          ? Row(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  child: IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.edit), onPressed: () {}),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  child: IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                      onPressed: () {}),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          : Container()),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        setState(() {
          final item = componentList[oldIndex];
          componentList[oldIndex] = componentList[newIndex];
          componentList[newIndex] = item;
        });
      },
    );
```

The behaviour is correct, but I want that it's shown on only one tile at time.

Comment: You just like to see the effect on hover item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using bool use nullable int to track the hover index.

```dart
  int? hoverItemIndex;
```

And perform the condition like

```dart
 MouseRegion(
  onEnter: (details) =>
      setState(() => hoverItemIndex = index),
  onExit: (details) =>
      setState(() => hoverItemIndex = null),
  onHover: (details) =>
      setState(() => hoverItemIndex = index),
```

Chaning ui will be

```dart
 hoverItemIndex == index ? Row(...) :
```

or just use `if(hoverItemIndex == index) Row(...)`

Answer (score 0):

All of ListTiles are using/sharing the same isHover boolean variable. To solve this, you should store the hover index instead of hover state (boolean), then you will test if index==hover index in the loop.

```
int? hoverIndex;
onEnter: (details) => setState(() => hoverIndex = index),
          onExit: (details) => setState(() => hoverIndex = null),
          onHover: (details) => setState(() => hoverIndex = index),
child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                  color: index == hoverIndex
                      ? Colors.grey.shade100
                      : Colors.transparent,
```

Hope this helps.